# Why only just position value with relative and static work with float?

Tags: html, css

I try to use:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
```

Also,

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
}
```

and does not work, only the float works well when I have:

> position: static or relative;

Why?

Comment: because it's called CSS syntax and the rules are set that way.

Comment: @MisterJojo what do you mean by *it's called CSS syntax*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position):

> This property specifies whether a box should float to the left, right, or not at all. It may be set for any element, **but only applies to elements that generate boxes that are not absolutely positioned.**

Worth to note that `position:fixed` is a particular case of `position:absolute`

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)</sup>

In other words, float can be set to any element but has no effect when `position` is either `absolute` or `fixed`